# Subtraction SUMs of values in first column (Amount) grouped by another second column (Products) with condition in another third column (Process)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could somebody help me with this issue, please?

***Note:** At first, I would like to apologize for my english...* :)

### Description

#### Situation

I have table of production records.
In this table are data with processed amounts on each process of production.

Processes in production must be chronological like: *Process-**1** → Process-**2** → Process-**3** → etc.*, but production of products doesn't have to be chronological.

#### Question

I want to use query on some process (any *Process* except of *Process-**1***) and I would like to know what amount of each product is available for this process.

I mean: I want to know amount of processed products from previous process substracted of amount of processed products on current process.

### Example

#### Data table

*Production:*

`| DataID | Product | Amount | Process |
|--------|---------|--------|---------|
|   1    |   P1    |   50   |    1    |
|   2    |   P2    |   40   |    1    |
|   3    |   P1    |   25   |    1    |
|   4    |   P1    |   60   |    2    |
|   5    |   P2    |   20   |    1    |
|   6    |   P3    |   75   |    1    |
|   7    |   P2    |   30   |    2    |
|   8    |   P1    |   35   |    3    |
|   9    |   P2    |   10   |    3    |
|   10   |   P3    |   50   |    2    |`

#### Requirements

Query for **Process 2**

*Process 2:*

`| Process | Product | Amount |
|---------|---------|--------|
|    2    |   P1    |   15   |
|    2    |   P2    |   30   |
|    2    |   P3    |   25   |`

Because:

**P1** = 50 + 25 - 60 = **15**

**P2** = 40 + 20 - 30 = **30**

**P3** = 75 - 50 = **25**

Query for **Process 3**

*Process 3:*

`| Process | Product | Amount |
|---------|---------|--------|
|    3    |   P1    |   25   |
|    3    |   P2    |   20   |
|    3    |   P3    |   50   |`

Because:

**P1** = 60 - 35 = **25**

**P2** = 30 - 10 = **20**

**P3** = 50 = **50**

### I tried...

#### Using of SELF JOIN

(Grouped by Products)

```
SELECT SUM(A.Amount)-SUM(B.Amount) FROM Data A, Data B
WHERE A.Process = 1 AND B.Process = 2
GROUP BY A.Product
```

It looks good, but results are wrong...

#### Using of SubSelects #1

```
SELECT (X - Y) AS 'Amount' FROM
(SELECT SUM(Amount) AS X FROM Data WHERE Process = 1),
(SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Y FROM Data WHERE Process = 2)
```

It works, but only for *Product-**1*** (probably because it is first in Data table).

#### Using of SubSelects #2

```
SELECT
((SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Data WHERE Process = 1 GROUP BY Product) - 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Data WHERE Process = 2 GROUP BY Product)) AS 'Amount'
```

This gets the same result as in ***Using of SubSelects #1***...

### Thank You a lot

Comment: If you have 2 line of process 2, what will happen? E.g `4_P1_60_2` and `11_P1_30_2` then `Query for Process 2`, P1 will has result=?

Comment: This situation should not occur and it will be prevented in application...
As You can see, in current situation are on process 2 available 15 pieces of product P1.
So on process 2 You can use max 15 pieces and not more...

Comment: Do you use `SQL Server` or `SQLite`? Please remove inappropriate tag.

Comment: I use SQL, but in SQLite i used to trying some tests...
OK, done. :)

Comment: What if you query process 4, will P3 continuing keep value 50?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because some Product may be or may not in some Process, first we must collect all the valid Products and only then calculate the result
Here the code I've just tested on your data:

```
with all_prod as (select distinct Product from t1)
select  
  ap.Product, coalesce(B.Amount,0) - coalesce(A.Amount,0) Amount
  from all_prod ap
  left join (
  select SUM(Amount) Amount, Product, 2 Process 
    from t1 
    where Process = 2
    group by Product, Process) A on A.Product = ap.Product
  left join (
  select SUM(Amount) Amount, Product, 2 Process 
    from t1 
    where Process = 1
    group by Product, Process) B on ap.Product = B.Product
```

It calculates values for a Process 2, to get the result for a Process 3 you should change values in a `where` clause

Answer (score 0):

You could use this, change number `2` to your process number (4 places to replace):

This work for SQLServer 2005+

```
WITH total_in_process AS 
(
    SELECT product, process,
        SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY product, process
)
SELECT 2 AS process,
    t1.product AS product,
    COALESCE(t1.amount, 0) - COALESCE(t.amount, 0) AS amount
FROM total_in_process t1
LEFT JOIN total_in_process t
ON t1.product = t.product AND t1.process = t.process - 1
WHERE COALESCE(t.process, 2) = 2 AND t1.process = 2 - 1 
ORDER BY t1.product;
```

This is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff6b8/4112)

`Edited`: In case you have process 4 and you want to get remaining value from last process (process 2/ 1 not 3) then you should use this query:

```
WITH all_product AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT product
    FROM table_name
)
, total_in_process AS 
(
    SELECT product, process,
        SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY product, process
)
, last_process AS 
(
    SELECT product, 
        MAX(process) AS last_process
    FROM total_in_process
    WHERE process < 4
    GROUP BY product
)
, last_process_value AS 
(
    SELECT t.product, t.process, t.amount
    FROM total_in_process t 
    INNER JOIN last_process l
    ON t.product = l.product AND t.process = l.last_process
)
SELECT 4 AS process,
    p.product,
    COALESCE(l.amount, 0) - COALESCE(t.amount, 0) AS amount
FROM all_product p
LEFT JOIN total_in_process t
ON p.product = t.product AND t.process = 4 
LEFT JOIN last_process_value l
ON l.product = p.product 
ORDER BY p.product;
```